# How to build URL of WCF REST web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest

I am using the new .NET 4 WCF REST web services. In order to link resources, I'd like to put links in my responses. In ASP.NET I can generate URLs from my routing configuration (e.g. UrlHelper.Action(...))

With WCF REST web services I have an ASP.NET routing configuration plus Uri templates:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}")]
MyResult Index(string id) {...}
```

I want to store related URIs in my result objects. How can I construct URLs from my routing configuration + UriTemplates without hardcoding base URLs or other information? Are there similar helper classes available?

Regards
Hartmut